# Localhost in Mac development

Tags: macos, apache, webserver

I am developing a MAC application wherein I have to decode few images using an api
I have enabled Web sharing on MAC and on giving the path http ://IPaddress/~User_name able to see the images on browser stored in the path Mac HD/User/username/sites/images. I am using the same path as above but the api is giving an eror, I suspect due to ~ in the path.I tried giving another weburl(hosted on web) and it worked. Also, I tried giving the absolute path(http://IP address/HD Mac/users/username/sites/images) as well but still getting the error.How and where can I change this setting? Is it in apache settings file ? Or how can I get the absolute path which will work?
I want to decode these images via the api which are there locally on my system and don't want to upload them over web
Please help.

Comment: Where and what is that API, what error is it giving you? Also, what IP address are you using?

Comment: IP address is my system IP on enabling web sharing on MAC, third party api is being used to decode the image.The api successfully return the value after decrypting the image.~ is the problem as mentioned by me earlier.

Comment: So that API is "somewhere out on the internets" I assume, and your computer is at home behind your internet access point/router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into simple networking issues. You are at home in your own intranet, accessing your own computer from your own computer. Your computer and its web server are only accessible from your own computer or from other computers on the same subnet. Computers from outside your subnet, i.e. anyone not with you behind your home router, has no access to anything inside your network. And neither should they, because you certainly don't want to expose your computer to the general public on the internet. Find some other way to upload those files to the API.

Comment: Thanks Deceze for the explanation.